# How to implement annotations for custom class fields and implement the save method of Service to clean up the fields of the class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, aop

I have three Class

```java
public class A {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private int validate;
}

public class B {
  private int id;
  private LocalDateTime modifiyTime;
}

public class C {
  private int id;
  private int sequence;
}
```

I want more abstract at the Service layer, so BaseService was designed

```java
public interface BaseService<T> {
  default void saveCheck(T t) {
      clear(t);
      duplicateCheck(t);
      preProcess(t);
      if(save(t)) {
        postProcess(t);
      }
  }
  
  void duplicateCheck(T t);
  
  void clear(T t);

  void preProcess(T t);

  boolean save(T t);

  void postProcess(T t);
}
```

I want to design an annotation `@ClearFiled`, marked on the entity's field, like this

```
public class A {
  @ClearFiled
  private int id;
  private String name;
  @ClearFiled
  private int validate;
}
```

Its effect is to replace the following code

```java
public interface IAService extends BaseService<A> {

}

public class AServiceImpl extends IAService {
  // @ClearFiled is used to omit this part of the code
  // this method belong to BaseService
  @Override
  public void clear(A a) {
    a.setId(0);
    a.setValidate(0);
  }
}
```

How do i do this?

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I read your question 3x, but am still unable to understand it. Maybe we have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898) here, and your question is focusing too much on **how** you want to technically solve a problem instead of explaining **what** you want to do and which problem you are trying to solve. BTW, what is `ClearFiled` supposed to mean? Do you mean something like `ClearField` perhaps? I am sure that someone here can help you, if you help the community to understand your question better.